# How to display values contained in LIST in a MAP stl: C++

Tags: c++, file, stl

[image]

I have a function where I am storing all the directories and its corresponding files.

I am facing problem in displaying the of VALUE the map. I have debugged and observed that the corresponding values are getting stored properly but I am not able to display it. Since value part of map is itself a list of pathiterator. Whenever I am getting same filename at different directory I am storing the reference or pathiterator in the map corresponding to the same key(file name). Kindly look into it.

```
void search()
      {
          using path_1 = std::string;     
          using paths_1 = std::set<path_1>;
          using pathiter = paths_1::iterator;
          using listofiter = std::list<pathiter>;
          using file = std::string;
          using store = std::map<file, listofiter>;
          using store_iter = store::iterator;
          paths_1 pp;
          pathiter oo;
          store s6;
          for (recursive_directory_iterator i("."), end; i != end; ++i)
          {
              pp.insert(i->path().parent_path());
              oo = pp.find(i->path().parent_path());
              
              if (!is_directory(i->path()))
              {
                  s6[i->path().filename()].push_back(oo);
              }
          }
          store_iter d;
          for ( d = s6.begin(); d != s6.end(); d++)
          {
              cout << "Key: " << d->first << "  Value: "<<d->second;
                                                         // ^^not able 
//to print it!! 
    
          }
   }
```

I have added screenshot that I took while debugging. If the same file is present at different location the `d->second {size}` will be more than 1.

I thought of applying loop: Here is what I did. I think I messed it up.

```
  for ( d = s6.begin(); d != s6.end(); d++)
          {
              cout << "Key: " << d->first << "  Value: ";
              for (int i = 0; i < d->second.size; i++)
              {
                  cout << d->second[i];
                                 //  ^^Error at this place
              } 
          }
```

ERROR: while using loop in a loop

[image]

Comment: Don't use `using` that way. It just makes your code harder to read.

Comment: @tanz: Please read the " how to ask"  guidance for this site. In particular, don't say that you have "an"  error. Show us the actual error.

Comment: In your edit `d->second` is a `listofiter` which has a begin and an end and need a loop, its elements are `pathiter` which is an iterator to a set, which also needs to be run in a loop, each element there is the actual path string.

Comment: @tanz: That's unreadable and unsearchable. Include the actual text. It's not just us, both the search engine on this site and search engines on the whole web prefer error messages in text.

Comment: @MSalters : You have already figured out the error. Its the same error which you mentioned in one of the comment below. You are right.

Comment: do I need to create another iterator for the list of iter i.e, for the VALUE map is storing and do something like  for '(t = d->second.begin(); t != d->second.end(); t++'  'cout<<*t'

Comment: @tanz: You can answer that yourself, if only by trying.

Comment: ya.. I am trying..thanks..

Comment: do I need to overload << ?? Never thought just printing gonna be so complex..

Answer (score 1):

`<< d->second` does not work because that is a collection.

You already knew one way to display a collection, using a `for( ; ; )` loop. Since you have a container inside a container, you would need a for-loop inside a for-loop to print all elements.

As a bonus, here's how you can write more compact loops:

```
for (auto&& element : container) { ...
```

No need for iterators, begin and end calls. That's all handled for you. The body of the loop is executed once for each element in the container. Same restrictions apply: don't try to add or remove elements while inside the loop.

[edit]
You added a new, third kind of for-loop. For some reason you now tried to use `for(int i = 0; i != container.size; ++i)` to iterate over a container. Why? You already know one way that works, and I just showed you another way that works.

BTW, the reason that it doesn't work is that `[i]` requires `operator[]`, which is not present in most containers. `begin/end` is present in all containers.

Comment: I had tried applying loop in a loop. But I think I messed it even more. I have added the code snippet of what I attempted in the question above. ( (loop in a loop). Kindly bear with me.

Comment: Yes sounds right, s6 is map of lists of sets of strings.